# Let $P$ a $\pi$-system. then the generated $\lambda$-system for $P$ coincides with the generated $\sigma$-algebra for $P$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $P$ a $\pi$-system. then the generated $\lambda$-system for $P$ coincides with the generated $\sigma$-algebra for $P$.

$D(P)=\sigma(P)$

where $D(P)$ is the Dynkin system.

**Definition:** We say $C$ is a $\lambda$-system if: 
i) $\emptyset\in C$
ii) $A,B\in C$ with $A\subset B$ then $B-A\in C$
iii) $\forall (A_n) \text{ Where this is a increasing sequence}\subset C \implies \bigcup A_n\in C$

**Definition:** We say $C$ is a $\pi$-system if 
i)$A,B \in C$ then $A\cap B\in C$

**My attempt:**

I want use this result: Let $A$ an algebra and $m$ a monotone class such that $A\subset m$ then $\sigma(A)\subset m$

I make this part of the proof.

Let see $D(P)\subset \sigma(P)$

As $P$ is a $\pi$-system then for $A,B\in P$ we have $A\cap B\in P \tag 1$ .

By hyptohesis we have P is a generated Dynkin system then:

i) $\emptyset \in P$
ii) $A,B\in P\text{ with }A\subset B\implies B-A\in P$
iii)$\forall (A_n)\uparrow\subset P\implies \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in P$

Then of $(1)$ and the hypothesis of $D(P)$ we have $D(P)$ is a ring and moreover is a monotone class, then by theorem $D(P)$ is a $\sigma$-ring

This implies
$\forall A_n\in P , \,\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\in P \tag2 $

Moreover,

> I need prove if $A\in P\implies A^c\in P$

For the other implication:

Let see $\sigma(P)\subset D(P)$

Let $B_0=\emptyset$, $B_1=A_1$, $B_2=A_2-A1$...  $B_n=A_n-A_{n-1}$

Then $(B_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a increasing sequence such that $(B_n)_{n\geq 1}\in P$

This implies $\bigcup B_n \in P$ this is for $\sigma(P)$

Then, $\sigma(P)$ is a dynking system. But $D(P)$ It's the smallest Dinking system. this implies

$\sigma(P)\subset D(P)$

Comment: It's indeed true that $\sigma (P)\subset \lambda (P)$, but since $\lambda (P)$ is not necessarily a $\sigma -$algebra, there is no reason to have the equality... Is it the precise statement of your exercise ? (Notice that it may be true, but since I've never heard about such a result, I'm quite surprised...)

Comment: Yes, is a theorem of a book of my course of measure-theory @Surb

Comment: I edit my answer @Surb

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow (please recall me if I forget).